# query date that is modified in document

Tags: mongodb

How can I make a query on mongodb that says: `currentTime <= endDate + 7 days` or `endDate + 7 days >= currentTime`?

If I do something like this `endDate: { $lte: (current + 7 days) }` (ignore the date calculation) it will grab all records from beginning that the endDate less than 7 days from now.

Basically I want to find records that **is not ended yet** after 7 days from the end date.

Comment: try this "endDate" : { "$lte" : new Date(ISODate().getTime() - 1000 * 3600 * 24 * 7) }

Comment: Do you mean the records should be between today and today+7 days?

Comment: @Satya that's the 7 days calculation after the endDate. As I said, that will return pretty much all records that the endDate is less than 7 days from now, not the ones that ended yet.

Comment: check the updated answer

Comment: @Satya hey I think that may work. I'll give it a go. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

try this  `"endDate" : { "$lte" : new Date(ISODate().getTime() - 1000 * 3600 * 24 * 7) }`